# Vue+FastAPI receiving 422 Unprocessable Entity when sending request form object for OAuth2PasswordRequestForm

Tags: python, vue.js, oauth-2.0, fastapi, http-status-code-422

I developing a site using Vue and FastAPI. I am currently stuck with the error:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity
```

received from a FastAPI Sever. As I understand `422` error cause when the request reached server but the request is in invalid format of data, right?

The route I am sending a request looks like this:

```
@router.post('/token',response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(form_data : Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()], db : db_dependency):
    
    user = authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password, db)

    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Could not validate user")
    
    token = create_access_token(user.username, user.id, timedelta(minutes=20))

    return {'acess_token' : token, 'token_type': "bearer"}
```

I understand that the request format for OAuth2PasswordRequestForm should be in the format of FormData() sending from a frontend right?

This is what I did in the frontend

```
login(username, password) {
            // Function to make a login request
            username = this.InputUsername
            password = this.InputPassword
            const formData = new FormData();
            
            formData.append('username', username);
            formData.append('password', password);

            console.log(formData)
            axios.post('http://localhost:5001/auth/token', {
                formData,
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    const { access_token } = response.data;
                    this.setAuthToken(access_token);
                    alert("Login")
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        },
```

I put both username and password in FormData() and send a request to server but still get `422` Error from the server. I have this route I'm facing an error on FastAPI api dashboard and it works perfectly fine this only happen when I tried to send a request from the frontend (Vue)

Can anyone guide me on what I did? Am I wrong here? or Did I misunderstand the request format of OAuth2PasswordRequestForm? Thank you

Comment: The body of the 422 error includes information about what failed validation. First thought is that wrapping `formData` inside `{}` seems wrong.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for pointing me out I didnt notice that {} was wraping the formdata. I solved it now thank you